# Можно ли получить прямую ссылку на файл с архива?

Tags: php, архивация

Можно ли получить прямую ссылку на файл с архива?
Например есть rar архив и в нем сжатый mp3 файл, как скачать именно файл а не архив?

Comment: «Напрямую» это минуя PHP отдавать файл средствами сервера.  
Значит искать надо модуль сервера, который позволяет это сделать.  
У Apache такого не существует, если я не ошибаюсь (впрочем Вы можете написать его сами). Другие сервера не могу сказать.

Comment: насколько я понял, его интересует просто "вытаскивание" файла из архива, как из папки.

Comment: А вообще архивировать музыку, как и картинки и видео, странная затея, к тому же при разархивировании будут тратиться ресурсы сервера, а нафига это надо?

Answer (score 2):

никак.

---

Если не считать, что можно по ссылке вызвать скрипт, который примет параметры, разархивирует архив и отдаст файл.

Comment: мальца не успел :)

Comment: ты просто печатал слишком много знаков вопроса=) Я же возмущался про себя=)

Answer (score 0):

Простите, а зачем?? ссылку в куда?? в архив? и качать прямо из архива?

вы для начала поймите разницу между файлом с точки зрения интернета и файлом с точки зрения ОС/ФС...

а так, берете необходимый класс для работы с архивом, "распаковываете" это все в память (это грубо говоря), вытаскиваете данные относящиеся к требуемому файлу и отдаете это пользователю с обратно с нужным header

Comment: можно ещё fuse использовать, но вообще с rar так делать не стоит, у него сложности с рандомным доступом (надо разархивировать почти все, хотя есть кажется режим в котором можно по одному файлу разархивировать, но все делают solid сейчас) вот с tar.gz или zip проще.

Comment: ну и да, согласен, но все равно это очень странная затея :)Мне просто интересно что могло сподвигнуть на такое решение.